# Нижний элемент наезжает на верхний

Tags: java, swing, gui

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. При схлопывании окна нижний JXTaskPaneContainer наезжает на верхний элемент (JTextArea). Происходит из-за того, что я в JTextArea в конструкторе жестко задал границы, т.к. необходимо было убрать большую пустую область между двумя элементами и зафиксировать Area примерно на одном уровне с Container. Часть кода - класс и конструктор класса ниже прилагаю. Как решить проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD - если убрать бордеры (EmptyBorder у JTextArea), верстка не едет, но теперь будет большое пространство между элементами, но необходимо, чтобы пространство было как на первой картинке, т.е. минимальное.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    private class ExtendedStatusPanel extends JPanel {
            protected JLabel serverNameLabel;
            protected JTextArea statusPanel;
            private final JPanel statusPanelWrapper = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
            private List<MonitorStatus> alertsGroups;
            private JXTaskPaneContainer jxTaskPaneContainer = new JXTaskPaneContainer();

            public ExtendedStatusPanel(final MonitorServer monitorServer) {
                setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                final JPanel serverNamePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(0));
                (serverNameLabel = new JLabel(monitorServer.getHost(), 2)).setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(12));
                serverNameLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                        monitorClient.selectDetailsTab();
                        monitorClient.selectServer(monitorServer);
                    }
                });
                serverNamePanel.add(serverNameLabel);

                jxTaskPaneContainer.setBackground(new Color(238,238,238));
                statusPanelWrapper.setLayout((new BoxLayout(statusPanelWrapper, 3)));
                statusPanel = new JTextArea();
                statusPanel.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Label.foreground"));
                statusPanel.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Label.background"));
                statusPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,15,-200,10));
                statusPanel.setEditable(false);
                statusPanel.setFont(UIManager.getFont("Label.font"));
                statusPanel.getKeymap().addActionForKeyStroke(ks, TransferHandler.getCopyAction());
                alertsGroups = new ArrayList<>();
                statusPanelWrapper.add(statusPanel);
                statusPanelWrapper.add(jxTaskPaneContainer);
                add(serverNamePanel, "North");
                add(statusPanelWrapper, "Center");
            }
}
```

Comment: `statusPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,15,-200,10));` может из-за отрицательного нижнего отступа?

Comment: Похоже что так, да. Но без этого у меня будет большое пространство между двумя элементами, но как его убрать - не знаю. Возможно ли оставить отрицательный отступ и профиксить баг с наложением элементов?

Comment: наверное надо лечить по-другому пустое место

Comment: Поделитесь секретом как вылечить?)

Comment: придется Вам собрать пример, иначе не понятно =)

Comment: окей, обновил вопрос)

Comment: попробуйте setPrefferedSize у JTextArea

Comment: это помогло, если задать 50 как предпочтительный размер, но теперь расстояние большое между элементами, и, даже если двигая отрицательный bottom, оно остается таким же

Comment: это layout растягивает, надо мудрить =)